# Remove Characters from Cells in Column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to remove characters from cells in a column as shown below.

[here is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycVgU.png)

I would like to use **Do While Loop** for consistency with the rest of my code. My code is like this (it might not make sense since I modified it from something else):

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 4).Activate
NewLastRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
CurPos1 = ActiveCell.Address
Do While ActiveCell.Row <= NewLastRow
CurPos = ActiveCell.Address
If ActiveCell = "" Then
Range(CurPos).Offset(1, 0).Select
Else
If ActiveCell >= 1 Then
Replace(ActiveCell, "READ", "")
End If
End If
Loop
```

I don't understand what is `CurPos1 = ActiveCell.Address` and `Range(CurPos).Offset(1, 0).Select`

Comment: CurPos1 is set to the position of the active cell, then it gets moved by the offset.

Comment: You really don't need a `Do While` loop here. Just use `Range.Replace`, i.e. call `.Replace` on the entire range.

Comment: `Range("E1:E10").Replace(DCREAD123,"READ","")` what is the syntax error in my code here? @BigBen

Comment: What is `DCREAD123`?

Comment: `Range("E2:E" & Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count).Replace "READ", "", xlPart, , True`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Range("E2:E10").Replace "Read", ""
```

Comment: beware this bug, though https://youtu.be/z8dGxce4lXs

Comment: You can work around that problem by first executing a `Range.Find` where `Range` is the range where you wish to do the `Range.Replace`. That will "reset" the "Workbook" search area to "Sheet" search area.